# fitting a distribution to skewed proportional data with negative values and bounded on one side

Tags: distributions, generalized-linear-model, modeling, skew-normal-distribution

I'm building a model to understand how different variables influence protected area performance at stopping deforestation (using counterfactual analysis).

My response variable is the percentage of baseline deforestation (matched sites detected with counterfactual analysis) avoided by protected areas. This is calculated as:

```
    (x-y)/x
```

where “x” is forest loss % in unprotected sites, and “y” is forest loss % in protected area.

Therefore, data is proportional, can take non-integer negative values, is negatively skewed and bounded (to the right) in 1, but has no "theoretical" bound to the left (deforestation can be higher inside protected areas). This is the distribution of the data:

[image: data distribution]

The number of point data is ~30, as this is the total number of existing protected areas.

Therefore, I'm unsure about what distribution and link function I could or, or if a transformation of the variable would be a better approach.

I think I can't use poisson or negative binomial because I have non-integers; I can't use gamma or inverse gaussian because the negative values (and data skewed to the right, which might be an atypical case for gamma?); I think I can't use beta because there is no bound to the left.

What would be the best approach to use this data in a modeling setup?

Comment: If none of your figures are going to be $0$ or $1$ (i.e. no no losses and no total losses) you might want to turn these into a logistic analysis.  In that case, you could consider something like a log-odds ratio

Comment: It would be helpful to know what null hypothesis you want to test and against what alternative, and why you have made that choice. // It seems clear from your histogram that there are more positive than negative values? Or are you interested in the overall avg, which is maybe about .4?